# Jquery: From a group of drop down boxes, get selected value from a chosen drop down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have many drop down boxes with different ids.

```js
$("select").change(function(e) {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id='priceType1' name='priceType1'>
        <option value='SRP'>SRP</option>
        <option value='DP'>DP</option></select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id='priceType2' name='priceType2'>
            <option value='SRP'>SRP</option>
            <option value='DP'>DP</option></select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id='priceType3' name='priceType3'>
            <option value='SRP'>SRP</option>
            <option value='DP'>DP</option></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, whenever I select an option from adrop down, how will I get the selected value. I have tried the code below but it is not working. I need to do this in jquery since I want to have an ajax code aftergetting the selected value.

Comment: this code will work

Comment: @Vineesh I know it should work but there are no alerts whenever I change an option.

Comment: Your code works, what's the problem? Can you describe the scenario and the expected behavior

Comment: You can verify in https://jsfiddle.net/e14muw6x/  I think you forgot to include jquery library

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rhc1yhvd/ there is an alert

Comment: you mean you want three values in the alert? or alert 3 times?

Comment: Make sure your javascript code is executed after DOM rendering or inside `$( document ).ready()`. Refer https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. Used `on()` with `change`. You can get selected value, as well as values of all 3 select drop-downs.:

```js
$("select").on('change', function() {
  console.log('Selected Value' + $(this).val());
  $("select option:selected").each(function(k, v) {
    console.log('Option ' + k + ' Value: ' + $(this).val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id='priceType1' name='priceType1'>
    <option value='SRP'>SRP</option>
    <option value='DP'>DP</option></select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id='priceType2' name='priceType2'>
        <option value='SRP'>SRP</option>
        <option value='DP'>DP</option></select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id='priceType3' name='priceType3'>
        <option value='SRP'>SRP</option>
        <option value='DP'>DP</option></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your code is correct but add select box change event written in document ready function ? that is the mistake.
```

JQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("select").change(function(e){
        alert($(this).val());
    });

});
</script>
```